# How to set property type of qml signal?

Tags: pyqt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I am learning `qml`,`quick` and `pyqt5` and write a small test script.

In this script, I want to drop something on my UI and print the url of it.

#### test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    id : root
    signal clicked(int x, int y)
    signal filedroped(list url)
    width: 800
    height: 450

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            parent.clicked(mouseX, mouseY)
        }
        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDropped: {
            root.filedroped(drop.urls)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The doc says:**Any of the QML Basic Types aside from the enumeration type can be used as custom property types.**

But I got error like this in `signal filedroped`:

```
Invalid signal parameter type: list
```

Also, I have tried `urllist` and `string`.
`urllist` failed and `string` works.

What's wrong with my script?

### EDIT

Since I use qml with pyqt, I do not want to use the type `var`.
With var, I'll got a `QJSValue` object instead of basic type of python in my python script.
Why qml performs different with the official document? Is the document wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems on there's indeed an error in the Qt Documentation. It is said ([here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#defining-signal-attributes)) that

> the allowed parameter types [for signal parameters] are the same as those listed under
>   [Defining Property Attributes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#valid-types-in-custom-property-definitions) on this page.

Yet one can define a property as follow:

```
property list<Item> items
```

whereas this is invalid:

```
signal mysignal(list<Item> items)
```

---

But anyway, the QML list type was not a solution. The [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-list.html) is quite clear:

> A list can only store QML objects, and cannot contain any basic type
>   values. (To store basic types within a list, use the var type
>   instead.).

In other words you can't use `list` to store strings, url, int. You have to use `var`. Another solution would be to use a formatted string with a custom separator instead of your url list, and split it on the Python side.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that urllist is an array of urls so you can use `var` in this case:

```
signal filedroped(var urls)
```

Comment: I do not prefer `var`, the details were added in my question.